# Как сделать защиту от отключения интернета для бота в телеграмм

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Как избежать накрутки телеграмм бота при помощи отправки многочисленных запросов в секунду с кнопки ? Php . Чистый api telegram

Comment: Думаю, что накрутки можно избежать только анализом идентификатора пользователя. Грубо говоря, на каждое событие "нажатие на кнопку" Вы получаете сообщение "такой то пользователь тапнул по кнопке". Смотрите, сколко раз он нажимал на кнопку, и можете ограничить обработку нажатия, если от этого пользователя прибежало слишком много событий

Comment: С помощью отключения интернета . И много кратное нажатие на кнопку приводит к накрутке